# What does {x:1} do in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

From Javascript: The Definitive Guide,

```
var o = { x:1 }; // Start with an object
o.x = 2; // Mutate it by changing the value of a property
o.y = 3; // Mutate it again by adding a new property
```

What does { x: 1} do here? With the braces, it reminds me of function (or for objects, constructor).  Can someone please elaborate on it, thanks.

An additional related question is:

```
({x:1, y:2}).toString() // => "[object Object]"
```

---

I find this question interesting as well. 
What is the difference between object and Object in the above code? In fact, when do we use Object?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It makes the variable `o` into an object containing one property (`x`), and sets the value of that property to 1.

### Edit

To be clear, as you demonstrated, you don't *have* to add properties this way. You can create a property on an object simply by assigning it (`o.y = "Awesomesauce"`)

As to your related question; `{x:1, y:2}` is simply an object literal with two properties x and y with the values 1 and 2, respectively. operating on this object literal is just like operating on a primitive value literal (`console.log("my,string".split(","))`).

`"[object Object]"` is just how a non-specifically typed object is represented in string form.

### Edit 2

As per your comment: the lowercase "object" is the type. `typeof o` will give `object`. The Object (capital "O") is just a string representation of `{x:1}`. A string representation of an array or number is "smart" because it knows more specifically the type. With a custom object, like `o`, it's just a generic object and thus writes: `object (the type) Object (a string representation of o itself)`

Comment: Sheidls 
Thanks. Very good answer. What now confuses me is "object vs Object".  x being the property is object? With the capitalization, Object, how is it different from object?  Thanks!

Comment: Actually. the object is {x:1}, and Object is the 1, right? Since Number(1) returns object,  Object(1) returns object (using typeof)... kinda confuse here.

Answer (score 4):

It's called *object initializer* (At least in C#). It creates a new object `o` and directly initiates the attribute `x` with the value `1`

Comment: +1, Not only in C#, in ECMAScript also, they are called [Object Initialiser Expressions](http://es5.github.com/#x11.1.5) (or just *"object literals"*) :).

Answer (score 3):

It's a JSON object, an associative array.  The key is "x"; the value is 1.

Comment: Don't confuse the object literal syntax, with the JSON *data interchange format*, they have [differences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975859/what-are-the-differences-between-json-and-javascript-object).

Comment: +1 for @CMS. It's really just a JavaScript object.  Crockford introduced the term JSON long, long, long after JavaScript was created.  Anyway, the string `{x:1}` is completely illegal in JSON.  JSON requires keys to be double quoted.  Check the official syntax: http://www.json.org.

Answer (score 2):

You already have answers to the first part of your question.

For the second part, you have called the `toString()` method stored in `Object.prototype`.

For fun, try this instead:

```
JSON.stringify({x:1, y:2})
```