# Using the some method in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays, `initialArray` and `testArray`. `initialArray` consists of 8 arrays each with a single element(an object), `testArray` consists of 8 elements (each an object).
I want to pop and push each of the elements in `testArray` to an array in `initialArray` when a condition is met so I end up with an empty `testArray` and `initialArray[0]..[7]` will each have one of the `testArray` elements.

```
var initialArray = [
    [{optiona:'some string',optionb: 'some string'}],
    [/*...*/],
];
var testArray = [
    {optiona:'some other string',optionb: 'some other string'},
    {/*...*/}
];
```

The final `initialArray` should look like

```
[
    [
        {optiona:'some string',optionb: 'some string'},
        {optiona:'some other string',optionb: 'some other string'}
    ],
    [
        {..},
        {..}
    ],
    // ,,,
]
```

My code so far:

```
var mySomeFunction = function(element, index, array) {
    // test if elements are not equal to (element.optiona != option1 && element.optionb != option2);
    //return the element
}

initialArray.forEach(function(item) { 
    //get the conditionals for the current element
    var option1 = item[0].optiona
    var option2 = item[0].optionb

    item.some(mySomeFunction)
    // item.push(element returned from mySomeFunction)
});
```

I'm not sure how to use the `.some` method properly, I need to pass the values `option1` and `option2` that relate to the current element e.g `initialArray[0][0]`, choose an element that values don't match the values of `option1` and `option2`, e.g `testArray[3]`, pop the element and push it onto the current array in `initialArray`, e.g `initialArray[0][0]` now contains the element `testArray[3]`.

Comment: Is there any way you could simply your example? This is a bit hard to follow (at least for me).

Comment: There ain't no JSON objects...

Comment: "{optiona:'some string',optionb: 'some string'}" isn't json?

Comment: @raphael_turtle: No. That's an object literal in the programming language _Javascript_. JSON is a text-based format that happens to look pretty much the same and is named after this syntax; in a language like Javascript, if you had JSON, it would be found inside a string.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975859/what-are-the-differences-between-json-and-javascript-object

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal : ah...understood, don't think it makes a difference to what I'm trying to do though..

Comment: @raphael_turtle: No, but the mistake is annoying!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `some` will be of much help here. It will either return `true` or `false`, so it does not tell you *which* element meets the condition.

You could use a normal loop:

```
initialArray.forEach(function(item) { 
    //get the conditionals for the current element
    var option1 = item[0].optiona
    var option2 = item[0].optionb

    for(var i = 0, len = testArray; i < len; i++) {
        if(testArray[i].optiona !== option1 && testArray[i].optionb !== option2) {
            item.push(testArray[i]);
            testArray.splice(i, 1); // remove element from array
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

Note that `forEach` is part of ECMAScript 5 and not available in older browsers.