# ng-repeat in AngularJS not binding properly

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am trying to render a **html table** with a list populated from my controller. This is what I am doing:

```
//Home Controller
app.controller("HomeController", function ($scope, $location, ExamService, AuthenticationService, $cookieStore) {

  $scope.items = '[{"id":"1","title":"Test 1","description":"this is a description"}]';


});
```

and in the page:

```
 <table class="table" ng-controller="HomeController">
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
                            <td>{{item.id}}</td>
                            <td>{{item.title}}</td>
                            <td>{{item.description}}</td>
                         </tr>
    </table>
```

However this generates as a blank table with 109 tr nodes...what I am doing wrong? please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is `$scope.items` is a string literal.

Instead, use an array literal:

```
 $scope.items = [{"id":"1","title":"Test 1","description":"this is a description"}];
```

Or shorter:

```
 $scope.items = [{id: 1,"title":"Test 1",description:"this is a description"}];
```

( [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PLtey/) )

**Why does this confusion happen?**

In my opinion this happens because people often confuse JSON - the data exchange format (which in JS you store in strings)and JavaScript object literals. `[]` is for an array object literal both in the JS language and with the JSON data exchange format. See [What are the differences between JSON and JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3975859/1348195)