# Javascript searching within json

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, underscore.js

Let's say I have a JSON object that looks like this, called "prices"

```
"Scrap Metal": {
            "defindex": [
                5000
            ],
            "prices": {
                "3": {
                    "Tradable": {
                        "Craftable": {
                            "0": {
                                "currency": "keys",
                                "value": 432,
                                "last_update": 1425334795,
                                "difference": 3491.64
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "6": {
                    "Tradable": {
                        "Craftable": {
                            "0": {
                                "currency": "metal",
                                "value": 0.11,
                                "last_update": 1336410088,
                                "difference": 0
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

This continues like this with a similar structure but different values. I want to search for the `defindex: 5000` value and then get the `value` from `6` from it. In other words, if I knew where it was in the code by searching the defindex, I would call `"name".prices[6].Tradable.Craftable[0].value`.

I've tried to use [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org) for this, but it didn't work. My code was:
`_.where(prices, { defindex: '5000' });`

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting the JSON response from a server request or is this a variable defined in JavaScript? If it's the latter, it shouldn't be called JSON: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975859/what-are-the-differences-between-json-and-javascript-object

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy it's from a server. Specifically http://backpack.tf/api

Comment: how do you map defIndex 5000 to value 6 (instead of say, 3, for instance)

Comment: You might want to take a look at this question: [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json). Please let me know if that answers your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use #find which allows you to use a function, iterates over each key/value pair, where the value will be what the top key points to.

```
_.find(prices, function(value, key) { 
  return (value.defindex == "5000")
})
```

Comment: Worked, thanks. Only thing is that you need a ) after the last brace.

Answer (score 0):

Since you might have a wide variety of possible queries and you're using underscore, you might like https://github.com/davidgtonge/underscore-query, as it provides Mongo-like query syntax: