# How to apply substring in json

Tags: json, json.net

I just think this is my variable getting data from  database 
I declare Description properties in separate class

```
public class Description
{
  public int DesID{set;get;}
  public string Description{
}
```

---

**C# Coding : Data**

```
[WebMethod]    
    public static List<Description> Data()
    {
      List<Description> listDescription = new List<Description>();
      Description d1=new Description()
       {
         DesID=1,
         Description ="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
       };
      Description d2=new Description()
       {
         DesID=2,
         Description ="thanks for your response"
       };
    listDescription.add(d1);
    listDescription.add(d2);
    }
```

**JSON :**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $(function () {

                $.ajax({

                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    url: 'WebForm1.aspx/Data',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    method: 'post',
                    success: function (data) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {

                            $('#divdisplay').append("<div>Description ID : "+ data.d[i].DesID+"<br/>Description : "+data.d[i].Description+</div>");
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert('Error');
                    }
                });

            });
```

---

### Important Note :-

I already tried this below code, but it is not working

```
$(data.d[i].Description).val().substr(1,5); And
data.d[i].Description.val().substr(1,5)
$(data.d[i].Description).val().substring(1,5); And
data.d[i].Description.val().substr
```

Comment: For us to help you, you need to rewrite your question.  1) Are you asking how to send JSON from c#?  If so, you should fix your c# compilation errors, add the tag [tag:c#], and explain what is not working.  2) Or are you asking how to parse JSON in JavaScript?  If so, the c# code is irrelevant.  You should [edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work) your post to remove it and instead include the JSON returned by the server.  Fix the tags to be [tag:javascript]  and [tag:json] and others as required.  See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Actually, does [how to parse json data with jquery / javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951810) answer your question?

Comment: By the way, [JSON is not JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975859/what-are-the-differences-between-json-and-javascript-object).  Your question includes JavaScript not JSON.