# eval() works but JSON.parse() and $.parseJSON() doesn't work

Tags: jquery, json, eval

I have a string returned from the server in my object property : (R.Message)

```
    "{
        error:{
            titleName:"||BroadcastableException_Title",
            errorDescriptionName:"||BroadcastableException_Description",
            errorMessageParameters:"",
            message:"\u003cb\u003e\u003ci\u003eBroadcast\u0027s status has been changed \u003c/i\u003e\u003c/b\u003e",
            stackTrace:" XXXX\\XXX.asmx.cs:line 851"
        }
    }"
```

I can use

```
(eval('(' + R.Message + ')')
```

But JSON.parse dosen't work

```
JSON.parse(R.Message)
```

I have this error :

```
Uncaught Invalid JSON: {error: {titleName:"||BroadcastableException_Title",errorDescrip .
```

Why Eval function can create object from this string but JSOn.parse can't?

I tried $parseJSON and I got the same error.

Comment: Because JSON is not synonym for JavaScript. Your string is just not JSON.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the differences between JSON and JavaScript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975859/what-are-the-differences-between-json-and-javascript-object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [JSON](http://json.org), object keys are type "string", and thus need to be quoted.  Your keys are unquoted.

Your web browser is kind enough to allow unquoted strings.

Comment: moreover, the object keys *must* be quoted using doublequotes

Comment: 4 up-votes so far for an answer that suggests that JavaScript/JSON syntax is a matter of browser kindness? ;-P

Comment: Alvaro: I can't tell what you're getting at.  If you think the score is too low or high, vote.  If you don't think my answer is very good, write a better one.

Comment: I'll clarify: both JSON and JavaScript are languages with a clearly defined syntax and, unlike HTML, the browser mustn't attempt to fix and run code that's syntactically wrong but throw a parse error and abort.