# where does 'this' point to in this JavaScript object's property?

Tags: javascript

I have an object like:

```
var Magic = {
  value: undefined,
  setValue: function (value) {
    this.value = value
    return this.value
  },
  one: this.value
};
```

and after I ran the following code:

```
console.log(Magic.setValue(1)) // 1
console.log(Magic.value) // 1
console.log(Magic.one) // undefined
```

Look at here: `Magic.value === 1` but `Magic.one === undefined`, since I assign `one:this.value`.

So why would this happen? Where did `this` on `one:this.value` point to? How can I assign `one` property with the value of property `value`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975859/what-are-the-differences-between-json-and-javascript-object for the difference between an object and JSON.

Comment: `one` refers to whatever `this.value` was at the time of defining the object. It does not re-evaluate every time you access `one`. It's no different than `var foo = bar` or `var foo = { bar: baz }`.

Comment: [Object inline declaration self references](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations)