# A function that compiles the JSON content with Handlebars templates is not working (syntax error?)

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, node.js, commonjs

There is a web page that is filled with content from JSON file using Handlebars (thank you very much **user6709129** for a detailed explanation of this technology: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38947838/6530539).

So I have:

- **Index.html**
- **content.JSON**
- **contentProcessing.js**

**contentProcessing.js:**

```js
function sendGet(callback) {
    /* create an AJAX request using XMLHttpRequest*/
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    /*reference json url taken from: http://www.jsontest.com/*/

    /* Specify the type of request by using XMLHttpRequest "open", 
       here 'GET'(argument one) refers to request type
       "http://date.jsontest.com/" (argument two) refers to JSON file location*/
    xhr.open('GET', "http://date.jsontest.com/");

    /*Using onload event handler you can check status of your request*/
    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            callback(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
        } else {
            alert(xhr.statusText);
        }
    };

    /*Using onerror event handler you can check error state, if your request failed to get the data*/
    xhr.onerror = function () {
        alert("Network Error");
    };

    /*send the request to server*/
    xhr.send();
}

//For template-1
var dateTemplate = document.getElementById("date-template").innerHTML;
var template = Handlebars.compile(dateTemplate);

sendGet(function (response) {
    document.getElementById('testData').innerHTML += template(response);
})
```

It works great!

Now I want to wrap the Javascript code in a function (let's call it `contentPrepare`), that uses three variables:

1. The path to the JSON file
2. Id of the Handlebars template
3. Div Id where the content should be placed

Then I want to use this function in the other Javascript file -  **addContent.js**, which will use this function several times with different variables, and thus fill the site with content.

**Why it does not work in my test example?**

```js
var jsonDir = "json/test.json";
var templId = "date-template";
var finId = 'testData';

function contentPrepare (jsonDir, templId, finId){
function sendGet(callback) {
    /* create an AJAX request using XMLHttpRequest*/
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    /*reference json url taken from: http://www.jsontest.com/*/

    /* Specify the type of request by using XMLHttpRequest "open", 
       here 'GET'(argument one) refers to request type
       "http://date.jsontest.com/" (argument two) refers to JSON file location*/
    xhr.open('GET', jsonDir);

    /*Using onload event handler you can check status of your request*/
    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            callback(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
        } else {
            alert(xhr.statusText);
        }
    };

    /*Using onerror event handler you can check error state, if your request failed to get the data*/
    xhr.onerror = function () {
        alert("Network Error");
    };

    /*send the request to server*/
    xhr.send();
}

//For template-1
var dateTemplate = document.getElementById(templId).innerHTML;
var template = Handlebars.compile(dateTemplate);

sendGet(function (response) {
    document.getElementById(finId).innerHTML += template(response);
})
}
```

*P.S.

Eventually, **contentProcessing.js** and **addContent.js** will be connected as a commonJS modules and compiled into a single Javascript file using  Browserify.*

Comment: What "does not work" exactly mean? Do you even call a `contentPrepare` function?

Comment: @zerkms
I connected `contentProcessing.js` to the `index.html` , using `<script type = "text / javascript" src = "contentProcessing.js">`. Then it works automatically: in the first example, if I run the local **HTTP server (nodeJS)** and open the page **localhost: 8080** I see JSON content on the page (as it should be). And if I replace the **JSON directory**, **Handlebars template id** and **html div id** with **defined variables**, I also see the content. But if I add a line `function contentPrepare (jsonDir, templId, finId) {code here}` - I don't longer see JSON content on the page.

Comment: So, you wrapped it in a function. Do you call it anywhere?

Comment: @zerkms Now I see my mistake, thank you!)

Comment: @zerkms If you will add an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have wrapped all your logic into a function - you still should invoke it (that's the whole purpose of having functions)

The call would presumably look something like

```
var jsonDir = "json/test.json";
var templId = "date-template";
var finId = 'testData';

contentPrepare(jsonDir, templId, finId);
```