# When to use a json file and when to use a js file?

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to do some declarative programming in javascript, where I create a spec and a chart should be rendered based on the spec. I was wondering if I should store the spec which defines the chart in a `json` file or a `js` file?

Are there any best practices for doing this?

I was also wondering(out of curiosity) why package.json is not a js file?

Comment: JSON is strictly data, js is not ... package.json is data

Comment: If you store it as a .js file you can use commonJS to export and import it into your js code. Just export an object with all the data properties that you need.

Comment: Refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975859/what-are-the-differences-between-json-and-javascript-object

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of stating the obvious, a .js file contains javascript code.  A .json file contains a JSON data structure, made up of a hierarchy of name:value pairs.  See: http://www.json.org/

I can't comment on your use case without further information, particularly regarding the contents of your 'spec'; but if it contains a JSON data structure, it would be a .json file.

package.json is a great example.  The structure is JSON format, so it's a .json file.  It is made up of a set of name:value pairs describing the package dependencies of a .js program.  See: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json

When creating and testing your spec, this will be a useful tool: https://jsonlint.com/