# How to extract data from JSON in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

How can I extract the following JSON in jQuery and show it in an alert box?

```js
{
  "ID": null,
  "ResponseCode": "0",
  "ResponseMessage": "Success...",
  "Data": [{
    "PARAMETER": "चुना",
    "QUANTITY": "500",
    "UNIT": "किलो",
    "METHOD": null
  }, {
    "PARAMETER": "सल्फर",
    "QUANTITY": "20",
    "UNIT": "किलो",
    "METHOD": null
  }, {
    "PARAMETER": "जिप्सम",
    "QUANTITY": "0",
    "UNIT": "MT",
    "METHOD": null
  }, {
    "PARAMETER": "फॉस्फरिक एसिड",
    "QUANTITY": "16",
    "UNIT": "किलो",
    "METHOD": null
  }, {
    "PARAMETER": "सल्फुरिक एसिड",
    "QUANTITY": "4",
    "UNIT": "किलो",
    "METHOD": null
  }, {
    "PARAMETER": "मल्चिंग ",
    "QUANTITY": "मल्चिंग",
    "UNIT": "-",
    "METHOD": null
  }],
}
```

Comment: Firstly, what you have is an object, not JSON so you can retrieve the data as you normally would from an object. Secondly, jQuery is useless here. It's for amending the DOM, not reading from an object. Thirdly, exactly what part of this are you wanting to show in an `alert()`?

Comment: Fourthly, what have you tried so far and which part are you having difficulty with?

Comment: i want the result in alert as (चुना,सल्फर,जिप्सम,फॉस्फरिक एसिड,सल्फुरिक एसिड,मल्चिंग )   show it in alert  to user

Comment: $.getJSON("my url", function (data) {                    var names = ata.map(function (value) {                        return alue.Data[0].PARAMETER;                    });                    alert("Successfully egister" + names + "----------------------");                ;

Comment: low quality question

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan just wondering why this isn't `JSON`. It looks like it meets all the requirements to me but I must be missing something - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975859/what-are-the-differences-between-json-and-javascript-object

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald JSON is a format to serialise a string. People often use 'JSON object' (or 'JSON array'), when what they mean is 'An object deserialised from JSON'. In other words, at the point you work with the data, it is an object and the fact that it was ever serialised in to JSON is irrelevant.

Comment: @Paul Fitzgerald it's a perfectly valid `JSON object`, maybe he was referring to a `JSON string` ?

Comment: how I can get the result  from above code as (चुना,सल्फर,जिप्सम,फॉस्फरिक एसिड,सल्फुरिक एसिड,मल्चिंग )  in alert

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = [
{
  "ID": null,
  "ResponseCode": "0",
  "ResponseMessage": "Success...",
  "Data": [{
    "PARAMETER": "चुना",
    "QUANTITY": "500",
    "UNIT": "किलो",
    "METHOD": null
  }, {
    "PARAMETER": "सल्फर",
    "QUANTITY": "20",
    "UNIT": "किलो",
    "METHOD": null
  }, {
    "PARAMETER": "जिप्सम",
    "QUANTITY": "0",
    "UNIT": "MT",
    "METHOD": null
  }, {
    "PARAMETER": "फॉस्फरिक एसिड",
    "QUANTITY": "16",
    "UNIT": "किलो",
    "METHOD": null
  }, {
    "PARAMETER": "सल्फुरिक एसिड",
    "QUANTITY": "4",
    "UNIT": "किलो",
    "METHOD": null
  }, {
    "PARAMETER": "मल्चिंग ",
    "QUANTITY": "मल्चिंग",
    "UNIT": "-",
    "METHOD": null
  }]
}
];

 var vData="";

 $.each(data, function(index, element) {             
     $.each(element.Data, function(index2, element2) {
         vData+=element2.PARAMETER+" "; 
     }); 
 });

 alert(vData);
```

[See this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2wadj/154/)

Comment: but my json does not contain var data = [ ] it start with{ and end with }

Answer (score 0):

Is this the sort of thing that you are after?

```
var example_json='{"ID": null,"ResponseCode": "0"}'; 
alert(JSON.stringify(example_json));
```

Or if you want to be fancy

```
var example_json='{"ID": null,"ResponseCode": "0"}'; 
alert(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(example_json)));
```