# Typescript array initialization

Tags: typescript

here I define the variable `results` to be an array of strings:

```
let results: string[];
```

and here below, I assign a value to kick things off:

```
results['searchCaption'] = "";
```

and then, the show stops with `ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'searchCaption' of undefined`

What am I missing here? Do I need to define an interface for it first?

Comment: Did you initialize the array? IE: `let results: string[] = []`? It would appear from the error that results is undefined, indicating that you never assigned anything to it.

Comment: `string[]` only defines what type the variable is. It doesn't assign anything to it.

Comment: `results['searchCaption'] = "";` is not a valid array syntax. Arrays are index based - objects are key based.

Comment: Perfect pointer! Sure that is it.  All along, I was thinking that `let results: string[]; ` would kicks things off with results = [] anyway! I think in ASP, it was not the case, my memory mislead me. Thank you! CRice!

Comment: Happy to help, but per @tymeJV's comment, you're assigning things to the array as though it were an object, which while possible, is definitely an anti-pattern.

Comment: tymeJV, that is a valid syntax; for 2 reasons: 1) typeScript tslint allows it. 2) when I did the init with `results = [];`, it does take it and I'm done with it.

Comment: did not know about the anti-pattern on this. so there is no such thing as ASSOCIATE ARRAYS like concept in typescript? No multidimensional arrays neither? Does that mean build all structures involving keys around JSON? Just got curious; do you happen to know why this would be an anti-pattern?

Comment: It's valid the same way that it's valid to use strings to store numbers – that is, the language specification doesn't stop you from doing it, but you're still using the wrong data type for the job. You end up with an empty array with a custom property.

Comment: You might be interested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874205/what-is-the-difference-between-an-array-and-an-object). And, based on the misuse of "JSON", [this question too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975859/what-are-the-differences-between-json-and-javascript-object).

Comment: JJJ thank you for the link. It will shed enough light for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you want is this:

```
let results = new Array<string>();
results['searchCaption'] = '';
```

Comment: I will accept the answer though there seems to be an anti-pattern about the use of arrays this way I came to know.