# convert string of numbers to array

Tags: javascript, php

I am asking about the best approach converting string formula like that     JSON input ["num1","num2","num3",...] to array in PHP 7 and in JS 
the array should be like that

```
$tobeconverted= "[\"1\",\"2\",\"3\"]" ; // consider escape character so ["1","2","3"] 
$number= array("1", "2", "3");
```

Comment: Php or Js? If you're having 2 different questions consider asking 2 different questions.

Comment: Yes, I want both PHP and JS

Comment: Then, too broad. Ask 2 different questions instead.

Comment: The input string looks like JSON. Use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) in PHP.

Comment: ... and there seems to be someone misunderstanding the question already. (deleted answer)

Comment: @user202729 l searched looka at the tobeconverted it's json input ["1","2","3"] not like your link "1,2,3" please read carefully

Comment: Note that [JS and JSON is not the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975859/what-are-the-differences-between-json-and-javascript-object). Misleading question.

Comment: Who said it's the same ????
JSON : "Object Notation " JS : Java Script

Comment: Your question...

Answer (score 2):

Conversion between "JS data" (JSON) and PHP can be done with [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
<?php
$number= array("1", "2", "3");
$json = json_encode($number);
echo $json;

# ["1","2","3"]

$array = json_decode($json);
var_dump($array);

# array(3) {
#  [0]=>
#  string(1) "1"
#  [1]=>
#  string(1) "2"
#  [2]=>
#  string(1) "3"
# }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I found. Hope it helps you.
PHP:

```
<?php
    $tobeconverted= "[\"1\",\"2\",\"3\"]";
    $arraystring = substr($tobeconverted, 1, strlen($tobeconverted) - 2);
    $array = explode(",", $arraystring);
    foreach ($array as $item) {
        echo $item . '<br/>';
    }
?>
```

JS:

```
  var tobeConverted = "[\"3\",\"4\",\"5\"]";  
  var array = JSON.parse(tobeConverted);
```