# Assigning a temporary variable to a JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I was trying to copy the contents of a particular JSON to another JSON and modify the temporary variable to my needs but the original JSON is also getting changed.

For example :

```
count = {
    passed : 2,
    failed : 5
} 
console.log(count)   // logs the JSON content
let temp = count;
console.log(temp)   // logs the JSON content
```

Say, now I'm modifying the temp, like :

```
temp.passed = 0;
console.log(temp);   //{passed : 0, failed : 5}
```

It is also changing the passed value of count too. Now if I log JSON of count,

```
console.log(count);    //{passed : 0, failed : 5}
```

where I want the passed to be 2, since I only modified the JSON object of passed in temp.

I want to keep the count to be same and modify only the temp. Can someone help me out ?

Comment: [That is not JSON, that is _an object_.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975859/what-are-the-differences-between-json-and-javascript-object)

Comment: you have to clone the object. you are just reassigning a reference.

Comment: are you using any libraries: JQuery, Angular, underscoreJs??

Comment: In your example temp is pointing to your count object. You don't have two object.

Answer (score 1):

First, [that is not JSON, that is an "object literal"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975859/what-are-the-differences-between-json-and-javascript-object). They are different things.

You need to *clone* the object, such as with a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```js
count = {
  passed: 2,
  failed: 5
}

const temp = { ...count };

temp.passed = 0;

console.dir(temp);
console.dir(count);
```

Or with [`Object.assign()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48671184/114900) and an empty object, proposed by Kenry.

Answer (score 1):

You must clone your object to add more properties and don't change the source.

Use `Object.assign()`

```
let temp = Object.assign({}, count);
```

In this way, you can add more properties without change the source.