# What is the correct term for a JSON object with methods?

Tags: javascript, json

If I have the following code:

```
var person = {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName : "Doe",
    id       : 5566,
    fullName : function() {
       return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    }
};
```

What is it called? Is it just a JSON object, even though it has a function binding? In the example I gave, could I call fullName a method?

Comment: That's not JSON, that's an Object Literal. JSON has very specific syntax

Comment: To add on, you can't have functions in JSON. Using `JSON.stringify` on the object that you provided, it just skips over `fullName`

Comment: ^^ furthermore JSON is **always** a string. It's a serialization format.

Comment: @kuwze did you checked the answer ?  I hope it will be as per your expectation.

Comment: @RohitJindal sorry I forgot to check your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the difference in JSON & Object literal [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975859/what-are-the-differences-between-json-and-javascript-object/3975890#3975890).

> - **person** is an object literal.
> - Properties (**firstName, lastName, id**) is like a noun which refers the **person** details.
> - Method (**fullName**) is like a verb that describes an action.

```js
var person = {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName : "Doe",
    id       : 5566,
    fullName : function() {
       return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    }
};

console.log("FirstName :", person.firstName);
console.log("Full Name :", person.fullName());
```

Here, person is an object. It has a property **`person.firstName`**, **`person.lastName`**, **`person.id`** and method **`person.fullName()`** that return full name of the person which include the person `firstName` & `lastName` property.