# How to modify a JSON structure

Tags: javascript

I'm pushing in a JSON structure some data and I have this issue as my structure should look at the next example:

```
{
  "data": {
           result: [{},{},{}]  
          }
}
```

What I have instead is is the:

```
result: [{},{},{}]
```

I need to push this structure as data:result but no clue how to do it.

This is what I did until now:

```
var parent_uuid = node.parent.data.uuid;
    var subject_data = node.data.subject_data;

    result = []

    var keys = Object.keys(subject_data);
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
      result.push({name: keys[i], label: keys[i], value: subject_data[keys[i]], type: "string", edit: false})
    }
    result.push({name: "enable", label: "enabled", value: true, type: "boolean", edit: true})

    _this.selectForm();
    _this.displayForm(parent_uuid, result);
```

Comment: why not `{
  "data": {
           result: result
          }
} `

Comment: Please read [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by [@str](https://stackoverflow.com/users/906113/str), read the following: [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975859/what-are-the-differences-between-json-and-javascript-object)

And to answer your question you can do the following:

`_this.displayForm(parent_uuid, { "data": { "result": result } });`

Comment: I did this but still, my structure is wrong. I wrote in the console this `result.data.leght` and result undefined. 
What I should have a structure like is in this past bin: https://pastebin.com/9VpHHBw1 
@KennyAlvizuris

Comment: @Jakub could try to do the following? 

`_this.displayForm(parent_uuid, { "data": { "result": result } });`

Comment: still don't see the right structure as the one I posted before I see this now https://pastebin.com/AfH3G1rc
There is no data still

Comment: Then it's something else @Jakub is there a way I could take a look to the complete function? so I can give you a jsfiddle

Comment: Great, I'm glad to hear. Thanks for the "up vote" ;)