# Json to javascript dictionary

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I have JSON data in the following structure, and I'm trying to parse it in order to work with the data using javascript.

#### JSON Data

```
{
    "FirstItem": {
        "id": 1,
        "type": "foo",
        "colours": ["blue", "black", "green"],
        "reviews": {
            "positive": ["The best", "unbelievable", "Awesome"],
            "negative": ["Sh*t", "Awful", "Dire", "Terrible", "Appalling"],
            "neutral": ["OK", "Meh"]
        }
    },
    "SecondItem": {
        "id": 2,
        "type": "bar",
        "colours": ["red", "white", "yellow"],
        "reviews": {
            "positive": ["Great", "Amazing", "Fantastic", "Perfect", "Uplifting"],
            "negative": ["Terrible", "Shocking", "abysmal"],
            "neutral": ["OK", "Standard", "Vanilla"]
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to parse this using `JSON.parse()`, however this returns the following error:

```
JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data
```

I have previously worked with this same JSON structure using C#, and had to deserialise this into a dictionary - information can be found on this post

#### Question

How can I parse this JSON into a javascript object, which will allow me to loop and evaluate each item?

Comment: JSON is a string. Your sample looks like a JS object.

Comment: It's already parsed...

Comment: You may not need to parse it any more.just assign in to a variable and use like `variableName["FirstItem"]`

Comment: Your right, this is already a javascript object, but how can I programmatically loop through each item? i.e. check the `FirstItem`, then check `SecondItem`, then `ThirdItem` etc...

Comment: For last comment see [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: Also appears that this would be better as array of objects where each object has the same property names. `[{i"id": 1, "type": "foo",      "colours"...}, {"id": 2,    "type": "bar", "colours":...}]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON is Javascript Object with double quoted key like what you have in sample. So you don't need to parse it again, [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975859/what-are-the-differences-between-json-and-javascript-object) for explanation. You can access data from it using its key or if in case you want to get reviews from SecondItem, you can access it with :

```
SecondItem.reviews
```

or

```
SecondItem['reviews']
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you are trying to parse an already parsed object

```
x = {A:1};       // A javascript object
JSON.parse(x);   // Error
```

this happens because `JSON.parse` will convert the object to a string first, getting `"[object Object]"` and then will try to parse this string.