# .map() is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to extract `date`, `expenseInfo`, `category` and `amount` from the expenses array. But I am getting `expenses.map() is not a function`.

Below is the code.

Where am I going wrong?

```js
let expenses = [{
    "user": {
      "id": "5bab847a5b0d2e2ce8b4cbe5",
      "name": "test_user",
      "email": "test@gmail.com",
      "username": "test"
    },
    "date": "07-Sep-2018",
    "expenseInfo": "Starbuck",
    "category": "Restaurants",
    "amount": 15
  },
  {
    "user": {
      "id": "5bab847a5b0d2e2ce8b4cbe5",
      "name": "test_user",
      "email": "test@gmail.com",
      "username": "test"
    },
    "date": "01-Aug-2018",
    "expenseInfo": "Shopping",
    "category": "Michael Kors bag",
    "amount": 90
  }
];

let expensesData = [];
let expenses1 = [];
expensesData.push(expenses);

expenses1 = expensesData.map((expense, index) => {
  `<tr>
          <td>${expense[index].date}</td>
          <td>${expense[index].expenseInfo}</td>
          <td>${expense[index].category}</td>
          <td>${expense[index].amount}</td>
           </tr>`
})
```

Comment: You push the `expenses` array into another array (`expensesData`) and that's the one you call `map` on, but from the mapping function, I think you expect to call it on `expenses`...

Comment: There is no such error in the console when you run this code. Can you share more  details? Probably you are running it on IE.

Comment: Do `console.log(expenses)` before `expenses.map()` and check the output... That will might help you and us also

Comment: I am getting this error in Chrome console. However not getting it in IDE.Not sure why

Comment: @ShravaniPL what is the log you are getting while doing `console.log(expenses)`

Comment: [{"user":{"id":"5bab847a5b0d2e2ce8b4cbe5","name":"test_user","email":"test@gmail.com","username":"test"},"date":"07-Sep-2018","expenseInfo":"Starbuck","category":"Restaurants","amount":15},{"user":{"id":"5bab847a5b0d2e2ce8b4cbe5","name":"test_user","email":"test@gmail.com","username":"test"},"date":"01-Aug-2018","expenseInfo":"Shopping","category":"Michael Kors bag","amount":90}];

Comment: What is `console.log(typeof expensesData)` right after the `...push()` line

Comment: @BruceWayne I am getting as object

Comment: @ShravaniPL so you are getting JSON string, not an array, you need to do `JSON.parse(expenses);`, then `expenses.map()` works without any issues

Comment: @JavascriptLover-SKT Thanks for highlighting this... My mistake. I was using JSON.stringify (expenses)  in some other method.Hence the issue

Comment: @ShravaniPL if that helps you glad. I also posted the answer. You can check and accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comment you posted what I observed is, you are getting expenses as JSON string not an array. You have to do `JSON.parse(expenses)`, then everything works as expected

```
expenses = JSON.parse(expenses);

let result = expenses.map((expense, index) => {
  return `<tr>
          <td>${expense[index].date}</td>
          <td>${expense[index].expenseInfo}</td>
          <td>${expense[index].category}</td>
          <td>${expense[index].amount}</td>
           </tr>`
});

console.log(result);
```

You can check the difference between normal javascript object and JSON Object from below links

[What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

[What are the differences between JSON and JavaScript object? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975859/what-are-the-differences-between-json-and-javascript-object)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Marked as answer

Answer (score 1):

When you push expenses into expensesData, you get expenses at the `0th index`. Either you ll need to avoid the `push` or try the code below

```
let expenses = [{
        "user": {
          "id": "5bab847a5b0d2e2ce8b4cbe5",
          "name": "test_user",
          "email": "test@gmail.com",
          "username": "test"
        },
        "date": "07-Sep-2018",
        "expenseInfo": "Starbuck",
        "category": "Restaurants",
        "amount": 15
      },
      {
        "user": {
          "id": "5bab847a5b0d2e2ce8b4cbe5",
          "name": "test_user",
          "email": "test@gmail.com",
          "username": "test"
        },
        "date": "01-Aug-2018",
        "expenseInfo": "Shopping",
        "category": "Michael Kors bag",
        "amount": 90
      }
    ];

    let expensesData = [];
    let expenses1 = [];
    expensesData.push(expenses);

    expenses1 = expensesData[0].map((expense, index) => {
      `<tr>
              <td>${expense.date}</td>
              <td>${expense.expenseInfo}</td>
              <td>${expense.category}</td>
              <td>${expense.amount}</td>
               </tr>`
    })
```

Comment: @ShravaniPL inside the <td> dont use expense[index], just use expense.date

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was using JSON.parse(expenses) which wasn't required at all. I have removed it and its working fine now

Answer (score 0):

```
let expenses = [{
    "user": {
        "id": "5bab847a5b0d2e2ce8b4cbe5",
        "name": "test_user",
        "email": "test@gmail.com",
        "username": "test"
    },
    "date": "07-Sep-2018",
    "expenseInfo": "Starbuck",
    "category": "Restaurants",
    "amount": 15
},
{
    "user": {
        "id": "5bab847a5b0d2e2ce8b4cbe5",
        "name": "test_user",
        "email": "test@gmail.com",
        "username": "test"
    },
    "date": "01-Aug-2018",
    "expenseInfo": "Shopping",
    "category": "Michael Kors bag",
    "amount": 90
}
];

let expenses1 = [];
expenses1 = expenses.map((expense) => {
   return `<tr>
          <td>${expense.date}</td>
          <td>${expense.expenseInfo}</td>
          <td>${expense.category}</td>
          <td>${expense.amount}</td>
           </tr>`
})
console.log(expenses1)
```

Comment: If you want to verify the code, comment html code and add a console.log(expense.propertyName). then run and check it.

Comment: ok. I  forget to add return statement. so that expenses1 variable will get value.

Comment: @ShravaniPL I have edited the code. Now expenses1 will have a returned value.

Comment: @ShravaniPL I removed index also which is not required.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was using JSON.parse(expenses) which wasn't required at all. I have removed it and its working fine now

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do this.

In a `Map` you need to return some value only then the `expense1` array will have values else it will be populated with `undefined`.

```
let expenses = [{
    "user": {
      "id": "5bab847a5b0d2e2ce8b4cbe5",
      "name": "test_user",
      "email": "test@gmail.com",
      "username": "test"
    },
    "date": "07-Sep-2018",
    "expenseInfo": "Starbuck",
    "category": "Restaurants",
    "amount": 15
  },
  {
    "user": {
      "id": "5bab847a5b0d2e2ce8b4cbe5",
      "name": "test_user",
      "email": "test@gmail.com",
      "username": "test"
    },
    "date": "01-Aug-2018",
    "expenseInfo": "Shopping",
    "category": "Michael Kors bag",
    "amount": 90
  }
];

let expensesData = [];
let expenses1 = [];
expensesData = [...expenses];

expenses1 = expensesData.map((expense, index) => {
  return `<tr>
          <td>${expense.date}</td>
          <td>${expense.expenseInfo}</td>
          <td>${expense.category}</td>
          <td>${expense.amount}</td>
           </tr>`
})
```

Comment: But according to my code expenses1 will definitely have values right?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was using JSON.parse(expenses) which wasn't required at all. I have removed it and its working fine now

Answer (score 0):

i Think you are trying to do this.
it works for me

```
expenses1 = expensesData[0].map(function(expense, index){return yours statement here});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was using JSON.parse(expenses) which wasn't required at all. I have removed it and its working fine now