# is python's json.dumps output safe for javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, json

I want to know if python's `json.dumps` method's output is safe for rendering directly into html/js script without escaping.

```
my_dict = {...}
my_dict_json_str = json.dumps(my_dict)
```

and then rendering this

```
<script>
    var my_dict = {{my_dict_json_str}};
</script>
```

Does this work every time or are there some characters that will break it?

Comment: I'd guess no, but I don't know Javascript very well. The question is, is a JSON value always a valid Javascript literal? (https://stackoverflow.com/a/3975890/1126841 shows some examples of valid literals that are not valid JSON, but nothing in the reverse direction.)

Comment: does `json.dumps` escape `/`? if not a simple `json.dumps("</script>")` would break it. ... does `{{ }}` do additional escaping?

Comment: @RolandStarke Yes; `json.dumps("</script>")` produces `'"</script>"'` (the double quotes are part of the value).

Comment: So `/` is not escaped. in this case its not safe to output it in html context.

Comment: *"rendering directly into a js file"*. That is not what you are showing. That is an html `<script>` tag

Comment: ok I reworded that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`json.dumps` is not safe for html use without proper escaping.

```
>>> json.dumps({"one": "</script>"})
'{"one": "</script>"}'
```

This behaviour can break your html.

Comment: Would add that JSON *in general* is not safe for rendering as HTML. Nothing specific to python about it.

Comment: so the next question is: is JSON safe for rendering as .js? and the one produced by `json.dumps` specifically?

Comment: But its pretty easy to make it safe. For example for `JSON.strinfigy` in js you only need to additionally escape the following chars: `['<', '>', '/', '\u2028', '\u2029']` see the following source code: https://github.com/yahoo/serialize-javascript/blob/master/index.js#L18 I would guess in python its similar.

Comment: Hi @RolandStarke thanks, please can you add this as an answer?

Comment: Hi, sadly I don't know enough of python to give a confident answer. (My "world" is more php and js)