# How to convert the json into array of array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, angular

> How to convert the below json into

```
var body = [{id:1,Country:'Denmark',price: 7.526,Location:'Copenhagen'},
    {id:2, Country:'Switzerland', price:7.509, Location:'Bern'},
  ]
```

> From above json into array of array as like below.

```
varbody = [
    [1, 'Denmark', 7.526, 'Copenhagen'],
    [2, 'Switzerland', 7.509, 'Bern'],
    [3, 'Iceland', 7.501, 'Reykjavík'],
    [4, 'Norway', 7.498, 'Oslo'],
  ]
```

Comment: Please take note that this is not a JSON, but a Javascript Object. JSON are strings

Comment: @Cid: _"JSON are strings"_ - could you please elaborate? What is JSON in first place? How is _it_ a string?

Comment: @MichaelD https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975859/what-are-the-differences-between-json-and-javascript-object

Answer (score 1):

You could destructure the objects and get an array with the wanted order of the elements.

```js
const
    body = [{ id: 1, Country: 'Denmark', price: 7.526, Location: 'Copenhagen' }, { id: 2, Country: 'Switzerland', price: 7.509, Location: 'Bern' }],
    result = body.map(({ id, Country, price, Location }) => [id, Country, price, Location]);
  
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Array#map` to map each object and `Object#values` to transform each object to the array of the object's values:

```js
const body = [{id:1,Country:'Denmark',price: 7.526,Location:'Copenhagen'}, {id:2, Country:'Switzerland', price:7.509, Location:'Bern'}];
const output = (arr) => arr.map(Object.values);

console.log(output(body));
```